# Unable to satisfy constraints warning on hiding element

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, constraints

I have UIView with some UI items inside it (Buttons, Labels...). There are constraints that help to fix this items.

I also have button for collapsing UIView. In this case UIView height is decreased and all UI Items inside it become hidden.

When I do it I have many warnings from Xcode in output section:

> Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints......
>
> Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint....

What can I do with it?

Comment: Post all of the error message. You have removed the important bit.

Comment: There is list of my UI items that are places inside collapsed view.